# Зачем нужна сборка для проектов, например, на PHP?

Tags: php

Есть такие проекты, как Capistrano, phpUnderControl, и так далее.

Зачем их использовать в пхп, когда можно просто закоммитить изменения в свн, сделать update на дев машине, и если там все хорошо, обновить код на продакшне?

Не понимаю Я, в чем профит от их использования. Объясните пожалуйста?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почитайте про continuous integration. Почитайте что phpUnit. Про тестирование.
Вообще обычно сам проект хранится в VCS, оттуда достается, прогоняются тесты различные (на синтаксис, на функции и т.п.) и если все хорошо, то оно узходит дальше по конвееру... если нет, то на доработку и все сначала.

я имею ввиду smoke тесты и более детальные тесты, которые запускаются в автоматическом режиме.

Понятно, что для очень мелких проектов это лишняя трата ресурсов, но в крупных проектах без этого никуда.

Comment: Эх, нету у нас никакого конвейера, как и тестов никаких нет. На машине девелопера работает проект, значит синтаксис - ок, логика - ок, гоним на дев машину для проверки другими чуваками. Если там все ок, апдейт на продакшне.

Comment: да можно и так, зависит от проекта, от требований к проекту.
Такие системы просто позволяют одной кнопкой сделать все нужные операции, как то -- вытащить проект из VCS, прогнать тесты, залить на сервер, перезапустить (если надо) какието сервисы... вообщем все, что будет запрограммировано для этого действия. ПОропбуйте, почитайте, может понравится.

Comment: Мне нужно то, всего-ничего: Чтобы перед заливкой на продакшн, или на дев в конфиге каждый раз автоинкремент версии проекта делался))

Comment: Ну эт понятно, почитать предложил для общего развития, я тоже всю жизнь без этого обходился, да и вообще без vcs, сйчас по работе столкнулся и понял чего мне не хватало до этого. :)